# Менеджер — это приказчик?

Tags: синонимы

По сути ведь приказчик — это "наёмное лицо у купца или в каком-нибудь торговом заведении, выполнявшее поручения торгового характера, занимавшееся по доверенности хозяина торговлей в магазине".

Есть смысл называть вещи своими именами.

Comment: А бизнесмен суть купецъ? :-)

Comment: Бизнесмен может быть и купцом, и промышленником, и предпринимателем. Все зависит о того, каким видом дела (бизнеса) он занят

Comment: А бизнесмен - делец.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Русского аналога для слова "менеджер" нет. Конкретно это заимствование не является проявлением той англофилии, которая, безусловно, имеет место. В данном случае аналога реально нет. Полностью аналогичное по смыслу слово можно придумать искусственно - "достигатор". Английское слово "manager" - это производная от "to manage". Основные значения: "суметь", "справиться", "смочь", а отнюдь не "управлять". Последнее значение тоже есть, но оно неотъемлемо обременено коннотацией наличия цели и ответственности. Проще говоря, управляющий неким процессом только тогда называется словом "manager", когда он сам ставит цели и несёт персональную ответственность за их достижение. А тот, кто получает цели извне, действует по инструкциям и не несёт никакой ответственности, называется словом "administrator". В принципе, в русском теперь есть два разных слова - "управленец" и "управляющий", которые вроде как призваны быть аналогами слов "manager" и "administrator". Но мне "управленец" не кажется удачным вариантом, поскольку предсказуемо вводит в заблуждение. Многие думают, что эти два слова - синонимы. Кроме того, слово "управленец" ничем не намекает на наличие цели, в достижении которой и заключается суть работы того, кто называется словом "manager". В общем, с точки зрения смысла "достигатор" был бы лучше, хотя это слово не слишком благозвучно. "Менеджер по уборке" (cleaning manager) звучит гораздо прикольнее, чем "достигатор чистоты". А "менеджер по безопасности" (security manager) смотрится более складно, чем "достигатор безопасности".

Comment: "Менеджер по уборке" (cleaning manager) звучит гораздо прикольнее, чем "достигатор чистоты".

Уборщица! Уборщик! А не менеджер по клинингу и не клинер, и уж тем более, никакой не "достигатор"

Comment: Уборщица - обычный исполнитель. Я же говорю о тех, кто выполняет организационные задачи.

Comment: И, кстати, все эти иностранные слова сильно напоминают  "Нью-Васюки".

Comment: "Нью-Васюки" ещё более-менее прикольно звучат. Меня больше всего пугает слово "мерчендайзер".

Comment: Просто Нью-Васюки нам с детства известны. Опять же, юмор самого произведения. А нынче? В СПб есть жилой комплекс "Твин Пикс". Почему - то название меня пугает.

Comment: Организует уборщиц завхоз. Зачем выдумывать? Что-то поменялось? Слова некрасивые? Конечно,скажешь, я клинер, не сразу поймут. что уборщица.

Comment: Завхоз - это качественно иной уровень. Он организует не какой-то отдельный вид работ, а хозяйственное направление в целом. В западной терминологии это называется топ-менеджер. Между этими понятиями такая же пропасть, как между моделью и топ-моделью. Первая получает 50 евро за то, что её сфотографируют для каталога OTTO, вторая - является лицом компании и стороной многомиллионного контракта.

Comment: >Полностью аналогичное по смыслу слово можно придумать искусственно - "достигатор". Английское слово "manager" - это производная от "to manage". Основные значения: "суметь", "справиться", "смочь", а отнюдь не "управлять". 

Не надо вот только отсебятины. У "to manage" дейстивтельно много значений, но "достигнать" среди них нет, во всяком случае среди ходовых. "Справляться", "удаваться", "руководить" - все что угодно. Но "достигать" это ваша фантазия.

Comment: Касательно вашей сентенции, кого называть менеджером - ну опять-таки личное мнение. Manager'ом могут назвать кого угодно, вплоть до посыльного. Дело не в целях и не в самостоятельности, а в определенном месте в сфере управления. Человек по должгности отвечат за определенный участок, производственный - или чем уж там фирма занимается, отсюда и управляение. 

Впрочем, всё это имеет весьма мало отношения к проблеме превода.

Comment: > В СПб есть жилой комплекс "Твин Пикс". Название меня пугает.  

Да уж, догадались назвать! Может, фильма не видели?

Comment: @behemothus Спасибо за ваш комментарий. Не обладая вашей бесконечной проницательностью, практически невозможно отличить чьё-то личное мнение от всего остального, ровно как и разобраться в том, что имеет отношение к проблеме перевода, а что - нет.

Comment: @DocentI Я думаю, это они убили Лору Палмер и замуровали её в фундамент этого жилого комплекса :)

Comment: @Shamov, спасибо за вашу высокую оценку моего нелегкого труда по разребанию отходов вашей жизнедеятельности. В следующий раз буду удалять подобное как не имеющее отношения к теме и обращенно лично к одному участнику. Для выражения отношения к сказанному здесь существует хорошо вам известная система повышения репутации.

Comment: Уважаемые, пожалуйста, мягше в полемике.

Answer (score 2):

Называть "менеджера" приказчиком, конечно, абсурд. Приказчик - архаизм (т.е. не может быть "своим именем" для менеджера). "Менеджер" в значении почти любого офисного работника с неясными функциями появился в России, как мне кажется, в начале 2000-х. Как раз тогда я вернулся из В/британии и был удивлён, т.к. там "manager" - это всегда человек, у которого в подчинении есть люди (т.е. наши соответствия - это начальник, руководитель, может, маленького, большого отдела, предприятия, склада; тот, у кого в подчинении есть люди, может быть и директор - general manager). Один бразилец недавно был сильно удивлен, что каждый второй в России - это менеджер. С точки зрения любого, кто более-менее уверенно владеет английским, manager - это тот, кто обычно имеет в подчинении людей.

Несложно доказать, что это слово употребляется в современной России зачастую не в том значении, которое имеет в английском (к примеру, БТРЯ Кузнецова дает близкое к английскому значение - "нанимаемый руководитель...", но население, похоже, думает иначе). Возможно, это нормальный процесс. Но хочется верить, что грамотность предполагает *осознанное* заимствование.

По-моему, популярность "менеджера" обусловлена необходимостью придать какой-то вес названиям ряда неопределённых должностей в современной офисно-корпоративной и потребительской культуре. Иными словами, моду на него, кажется, подпитывают не языковые, а социальные и психологические факторы.

По поводу *to manage* (у которого много значений, вкл. "справляться, смочь" и т.д.), *manager* (существительное) восходит к значению "руководить, управлять", а "справляться, смочь" семантически для *manager* - далёкая периферия.

Answer (score 1):

Я не в восторге от слова "менеджер", но иногда слова привязываются к определённой исторической эпохе. В общем-то можно и таксиста называть *извозчик*.

На территории бывшей Югославии вполне нормально назвать военнослужащего *ратник*. Для России это скорее воин тех времён, когда славянами правили князья и бояре.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что в слове "приказчик" больше связи с торговлей, а "менеджер" - с управлением. Впрочем, эти слова действительно похожи. Жаль только, что слово "приказчик" устарело задолго до того, как мы заговорили о менеджменте. Как-то нафталином попахивает.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то общее между этими понятиями, конечно, есть...  Но:

1. Менеджер - это не только и даже не столько торговля, сколько управление вообще.
2. Приказчик это скорее старший управляющий в магазине. Менеджер - любого звена, вплоть до посыльного.
3. Сама торговля сильно изменилась вместе с функциями персонала. А вслед за последними - и названия должностных лиц.

~~~ 08.09.12

Услышал сейчас по TV, как тренер английской футбольной команды без всякой афористичности и рисовки назвал себя менеджером. Это окончательно убедило меня в принципиальной разнице 
этих двух понятий.  
Как-то так:
Приказчик - конкретная должность в магазине или на предприятии массового обслуживания (Остальные случаи опускаю, ибо использование этого названия для должности, не вязанной с предоставлением услуг населению, сомнительно).  
Менеджер - вообще всякая штатная единица с фунциями управлния, этакое обобщение понятия управленца. Вот, пожалуй, "управленец" и будет самым близким соответствием "менеджеру". А "приказчик", если я правильно понимаю тогдашнюю систему должностей - "порученец".

Comment: Тем не менее было бы неплохо "возродить" старый термин, пусть и в новом значении (приказчик приказывает, т.е. управляет). Только это нереально.

Comment: Не согласен. Т.е. возродить-то можно, но кого им называть? "Генеральный менеджер" - это управляющий, остальных проще назвать своими именами. Логистик, рекламщик, кадровик... А не "менеджер отдела рекламы". "Приказчик отдела логистики" звучало бы уж совсем по-марсиански.

Comment: А *эффективный менеджер* -- *шустрый приказчик* :)  

Вообще-то (хотел ещё вчера написать) сама идея со словом "приказчик" мне где-то понравилась. Только можно ли возродить слово уже считающееся устаревшим? 

Многие знают, что во времена написания Пушкиным "Евгения Онегина" и имя Татьяна считалось устаревшим. Но потом стало широко употребляться.

Comment: Ну, мне кажется, что подобными новомодными иностранными словами пользуются, когда хотят запудрить мозги. Помню, девочку на работу брали на какую то непонятную функцию, после минутного совещания, назвали менеджером. И всё.
Это как с "демократий". Потом Дм. Медведев сокрушается, что народ перепутал "демократию" с "благополучием".

Comment: И, кстати, есть знакомые которые водителей (таксистов) называют "извозчиками". С юмором.

Comment: Ну и хорошо, что по-марсиански. Весело.

Comment: @behemothus Слышу слово "менеджер" каждый день, поэтому заглянул на эту старую ветку. В Англии manager - это главный тренер команды, обычно в футболе (что мы чаще слышим), но по словарю (OALD - a person who trains and organizes a sports team) в любом спорте. Вроде бы в США термин не в ходу (имею в виду только спортивный термин). Мог бы прокомментировать слово manager (поскольку жил в В/британии), если это актуально, ветка старая...

Comment: @alexsms *Мог бы прокомментировать слово manager (поскольку жил в В/британии), если это актуально, ветка старая* - дык комментируйте, конечно, если есть что сказать. По поводу того, что manager -"главный тренер", ну так это давно уже не секрет. Но это только косвенный аргумент в пользу моего основного тезиса. "менеджер" не равно "приказчик".

Comment: @behemothus , раз есть интерес, дал ответ. Возможно, дискуссия возобновится, но чуть на более серьезном уровне. Кстати, посмотрел: в США manager (field manager) используют в бейсболе (чисто бейсбольная практика), но не в других в.спорта. Насчет manager в футболе в Англии лично я узнал не очень давно (думал там coach, head coach).

Answer (score 0):

В свое время и Прапорщик было словом устаревшим. Приказчик тоже может  имеет смысл возродить ?
А главного манагера  можно назвать Главным управляющим